# Did any Quidditch games ever end by agreement of the Captains?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

> The game can only end when the Snitch has been caught, or by mutual agreement of the two teams' Captains; the latter is very rare, however, as one team would have to lose. (*source: HP Wikia on Golden Snitch*)

Is there an example from canon of this resolution to the game ever happening?

Comment: Odd, I thought the snitch was just worth a lot of points. Someone catches the snitch every game?

Comment: @GorchestopherH Yep. Every Quidditch game we see in the books & movies is ended by someone catching the Snitch. I feel like there may be some pro/international games that are discussed which don't explicitly state how they ended though so that's why I'm going with a comment =/

Comment: I think it's in the first book, someone is explaining to Harry how the game works, and they bring up the fact that some games lasted for days and almost weeks because the snitch wasn't caught. I think one of those occasions might be one of the times Captains came to agreement of ending the game, but I don't have details.

Comment: Quidditch seems like a low scoring game, hard to understand why they made the only thing that can end the game worth 15 normal goals.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - 150 Galleons are worth it (read up the history of the Snitch in QTTA)

Comment: @GorchestopherH Except when one team is either way more skilled or has far better brooms.  There was one match in the books where Harry was told by the captain to hold off on catching the snitch unless Gryffindor was less than 150 behind.

Comment: @Izkata I think you are thinking of _The Prisoner of Azkaban_, and it was if they were 50 points **up** not down, because otherwise they would win the match but lose the Cup.

Comment: @NominSim Hmm..  Probably right.  It's been a _long_ while since I've read them, but I thought I remembered that.

Comment: @Izkata There was the Quidditch World Cup where Krum caught the Snitch but lost...maybe that's what you were thinking of?

Comment: @NominSim Or maybe I just combined them in my head, 'cause I thought I remembered Harry being the one having to keep an eye on the score.  If it was raining during one of those matches, that's the one that's foremost in my mind.  If not..  forget about it, I'm probably combining _three_ matches in my head.

Comment: @Izkata Here's the quote from Azkaban:  "'So you must catch it only if we’re more than fifty points up,' Wood told Harry constantly...'or we win the match but lose the Cup.'" Plus (just because of your last comment) directly after is: "It looked as though the conditions for the match would be perfect." :) So you indeed might be combining three.

Comment: See the later question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/ What happens if the seeker can't catch the snitch? How does the game end?

Answer (score 9):

The wiki is quoting *Quidditch Through The Ages* correctly. The quote, worded exactly as the question states, is on page 23.

While I can't find an example of a game ending *specifically* by mutual consent of the team captains, page 23 also says this:

> There is a tale that the Golden Snitch evaded capture for six months
>   on Bodmin Moor in 1884, both teams finally giving up in disgust...

It's possible the team captains agreed, and it's just not specifically stated in the account.

Answer (score 2):

Philosopher's Stone chapter 10 contradicts this flatly.  In here, Oliver Wood, captain of the Gryffindor Quidditch team explains:

> ’[…] A game of Quidditch only ends when the Snitch is caught, so it can go on for ages – I think the record is three months, they had to keep bringing on substitutes so the players could get some sleep. […]’

Thus, unless some later canon overrides this, the wiki you're quoting is wrong.

Comment: I presumed that the wiki entry came from _Quidditch Through The Ages_ but if not then I believe you are right.

Comment: @NominSim - yeah, if anywhere it's likely to be QTTA.

Comment: Who is to say that Wood's knowledge is perfect? He seems quite unsure of himself in that quote...

Comment: Pearsonartphoto: he's unsure about the history. I think he's sure about the rules.  He could be simplifying the rules though, because Harry has never heared of them before.  He also doesn't list the “seven hundred ways of committing a Quidditch foul” (PS ch. 11).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see team captains agreeing, unless (a) they agree to a draw, or (b) the losing team is so tired that they've given up all hope of winning.

In any event, a Quidditch game can end in a tie the normal way. If a team is trailing by 150 points, and that team's seeker catches the snitch, the game ends in a tie.