# What happens if the seeker can't catch the snitch? How does the game end?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, quidditch, wizards

In Quidditch the game only ends when the Snitch is caught, but what happens if the Seeker can't catch it? The house in the lead would win, wouldn't they? Where do the teachers draw the line to the end of the game?

Comment: Guidditch?  Also, why can't I edit this?

Comment: @zipquicy The edit link will be greyed out if there's already a proposed edit pending approval and you don't yet have the privileges to review it.

Comment: See the related question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/ Did any Quidditch games ever end by agreement of the Captains?  That question has the same two quotes in answers.

Comment: Passing comment -- Quidditch would be a much better game if catching the Snitch only _ended_ the game and didn't add the extra points.

Answer (score 18):

The game can also end by mutual consent of the team captains:

> A game of Quidditch ends only when the Golden Snitch
>   has been caught, or by mutual consent of the two team
>   Captains.
>   <sub>*Quidditch Through the Ages* - page 28 - Scholastic - Chapter Six, *Changes in Quidditch Since the Fourteenth Century*</sub>

Comment: So if one of the captains refuses to agree, a Quidditch match can last long enough for all players to die of old age...

Comment: @vsz Like tennis?

Comment: I supose that eventually the destruction or banishment of the snitch should take the match to a forced halt.

Comment: Mutual consent by two captains means the game is a draw? Or does the team with higher points win. Because certainly no captain would consent if he's losing.

Comment: It seems to me that after four or five days even a losing captain might consent to end the game.

Answer (score 11):

Previous answer has a quote for *Quidditch through the Ages* so those might be the rules.
But I find it hard to believe that option was used very often :)

In HP1 Wood explains:

> "A game of Quidditch only ends when the Snitch is caught, so it can go
>   on for ages -- I think the record is three months, they had to keep
>   bringing on substitutes so the players could get some sleep."
>     -  HP1 Chp10

That seems in tone with the "Atmosphere" of the world. It's preposterous to continue playing for ever so I'll bet that just what they'll do!!!